# Access Index of Pivot Table in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

Is there a way that i can Access pivot table like below???

```
array:18 [
  "id" => 4
  "user_id" => 5
  "price" => 8659
  "created_at" => "2020-01-17 14:08:06"
  "updated_at" => "2020-01-17 14:08:06"
  "pivot" => array:5 [
    "purchase_id" => 6
    "product_id" => 4
    "quantity" => "13"
    "unit_price" => "3212"
    "discount" => "11.00"
  ]
]
```

I want to Update `Pivot` Table and i  tried method like below

```
       foreach($request->products as $product) {
            $purchase->products()->updateExistingPivot($product['id'], [
                'unit_price' => $product['unit_price'],
                'quantity' => $product['quantity'],
                'discount' => $product['discount'],
            ]);

            // dd($product);
        }
```

But got an error `message: "Undefined index: unit_price"`.

Any Help, Thanks in Advance...

Comment: did you try already this one $product['pivot']['unit_price] ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 not yet, lemme try first..

Comment: @Qonvex620 thats it bro, ur solution work perfectly..

Comment: if not, then you can access it like this also  $product['pivot']->unit_price, depends on what type your pivot is like array or object.

Comment: Thank's, glad to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you don't have `unit_price` key in your `$product`,

Try to call it by `$product['pivot']`

```php
$purchase->products()->updateExistingPivot($product['id'], [
                'unit_price' => $product['pivot']['unit_price'],
                'quantity' => $product['pivot']['quantity'],
                'discount' => $product['pivot']['discount'],
            ]);
```

Comment: I still got the same `issue`

Comment: @z3r0 It seems you don't have `unit_price` key in your `$product`